# Replace first occurrence in package.json file

Tags: node.js, bash, sed

Having hard time replacing only the occurrence of the `version` property value in my package.json file

what i tried

```
CURRENT_VERSION=$(node -p "require('./package.json').version")
sed  -i '0,/$CURRENT_VERSION/{s//1.0.2/}' package.json

-- file doesn't change --
```

my package.json file

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "demo-dep": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing json files with `sed` is too prone to errors, try to avoid that and use specialized tools for the job.

`npm` itself can be used to set versions hassle-free, see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-version

In your case running `npm version 1.0.2` should work

If you still want to use sed - something like this should work

`sed -i "0,/$CURRENT_VERSION/ s/$CURRENT_VERSION/1.0.2/"`

But if npm is not an option - i suggest you to use `jq`

```
tmp=$(mktemp); jq '.version = "1.0.2"' package.json > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" package.json
```

it will certainly be less error-prone

Comment: thanks for the replace, but my use-case is different - i need to change the package.json version value in the CI pipeline as the docker image uses that value

Comment: I am still not quite get the difference - both ways will result it changing package.json, to desired state, but i have updated answer with sed example and jq example, which is better suited for the job